# What are the transcripts at 0:27, 0:44, 0:54 of this BuzzFeed Video "Things Everybody Does But Doesn't Talk About ft. President Obama"?

Tags: listening

What are the transcripts at 0:27, 0:44, 0:54 of this BuzzFeed Video "Things Everybody Does But Doesn't Talk About ft. President Obama" (https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=1631492713658271&permPage=1)?

What I get are:
1.Prum??
2.Like any other Wednesday.
3.The ??? you can get health insurance for less than a hundred dollars a month.

And at 1:28 the man says "6 left in the game, down by 1", does he mean "the game only left 6 seconds, and his team still lagged behind one point"?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I hear "*prune.*"  I think he is practicing his enunciation while looking in a mirror to see how his lips move.
2. *"Not like any other Wednesday."*
3. *In many cases you can get health insurance for less than a hundred dollars a month.*
4. ***"Seconds** left in the game, down by one."*   Your understanding of the scenario is correct.  He is narrating the final seconds of a basketball game to himself while the time ticks away on the crossing light.  A field goal in basketball is worth two points, so his last second "shot" is the game winner, putting his team "up by one as time expires."

Comment: Just a random comment here. The **pru** in "Prune" is used to bring ones lips into kissing position (the word is well known for that). Or it is used in juxtaposition for how to properly enunciate the similar cluster *bru* in *Fe**bru**ary*.